# Nightmarejs .click() on each element with delay between

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, browser-automation, nightmare

I am trying to make simple follow script with Nightmarejs. It should work in next way:

1. Go to some user profile
2. Click on button to open list of followers of that user
3. Click all **follow** buttons with delay between each click
4. Click **load more**
5. Repeat *step 3. and 4.* few times

What I have so far is this, and it works with no errors, but it clicks only on first follow button and that is end:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

nightmare
.goto('http://example.com/')
.click('.buttonOpenModal')
.wait(4000)
.click('.buttonFollow')
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
  });
```

I tried to loop clicking on follow buttons like this but it gives me error **$ is not defined**

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

nightmare
.goto('http://example.com/')
.click('.buttonOpenModal')
.wait(4000)
.evaluate(function(){
    $('.buttonFollow').each(function() {
      $(this).click();
    });
  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
  });
```

I believe that for someone who is experienced in Nightmarejs this will be simple task, but I just started with it and been struggling with it for 2 days now.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get `$ is not defined` because this syntax is part of jQuery, when you write NightmareJS script it uses pure javascript.

You can load jquery library (before evaluateing) thanks to function `.inject("js", "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js")`

We need a synchronous sleep, else NightmareJS may end the function ̀`evaluate` before it finishes. (I found the code for `sleep` on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17532524/6479780)
If you want to try asynchronous sleep, you have to use `setTimeout(callback, millis)`
Here is what I would do, using pure javascript :

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

nightmare
.goto('http://example.com/')
.click('.buttonOpenModal')
.wait(4000)
.evaluate(function(){
    function sleep(ms) {
     var start = new Date().getTime(), expire = start + ms;
     while (new Date().getTime() < expire) { }
     return;
    }

    var list = document.querySelectorAll('.buttonFollow');
    list.forEach(function(elt){
       elt.click();
       //We need synchronous sleep here
       sleep(2000); //Wait 2 seconds
    });
  })
.end()
.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result)
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
});
```

Comment: I see. This works but it clicks all at once, could you edit with delay between each? And if I understood well, basically you can add any pure javascript function inside .evaluate ? Thank you!

Comment: The code in evaluate will be executed in the window opened by nightmarejs. So basically, it's like you open a new tab on your browser, you type the website address and you paste the content of `evaluate` function inside the console. That's why pure javascript works

Comment: Electron browser freezes when sleeping like this

Answer (score 0):

Try this version:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

nightmare
  .goto('http://example.com/')
  .click('.buttonOpenModal')
  .wait('div.Buttons')
  .evaluate(function () {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
      var btn = document.querySelectorAll('div.Buttons');
      if (undefined == btn || 0 == btn.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
      else {
        btn[0].click();
      }
    }, 5000);
  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
  });
```